# Sort one list by the order of another list

Tags: sorting, haskell

I need to sort one list by the order of another, but I don't know how it can be done.

For example: I could have a list `a` similar to:

```
[C, B, G, E]
```

And a list `b` (that sets the order):

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, ...]
```

(Just as example, these aren't the actual values though)

Then, list `a` should be sorted the same way as List `b` and thus become sorted to:

```
[B, C, E, G]
```

How to do this sorting by the order of another list?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand, one of the lists give the relative order of all the elements of the other list. Ie:

```
 > sortWithOrder [5,1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]
 [5,5,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

This piece of code should work :

```
module SortWithOrder where

import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sortWithOrder :: Ord a
              => [a] -- order list
              -> [a] -- source list
              -> [a]
sortWithOrder order = sortBy (comparing getOrder)
    where
        getOrder k = M.findWithDefault (-1) k ordermap
        ordermap = M.fromList (zip order [0..])
```

Edit: a more efficient solution is to use `sortOn`, like this:

```
sortWithOrder order = sortOn getOrder
```

Comment: In recent `base` versions, there's a `sortOn` function to avoid looking up the same keys in the map over and over. With older versions, you can copy its decorate-sort-undecorate logic.

Comment: Ah, I never realized it worked that way! I will update my answer.

Comment: the question admits types  with only the `Eq` constraint, not necessarily `Ord`.

Answer (score 5):

You could also map the order to the list and sort it:

```
Prelude> let order = zip ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"] [0..]

Prelude> let myList = ["C", "B", "G", "E"]

Prelude> import Data.List (sort)

Prelude> map snd . sort . map (\x -> (lookup x order, x)) $ myList

["B","C","E","G"]
```

Thus we can define this function as

```
sortAlong :: Eq b => [b] -> [b] -> [b]
sortAlong order = map snd . sortBy (comparing fst) . map (\x -> (lookup x z, x))
    where
    z = zip order [0..]
```

An `Ord` constraint allows the more efficient route through `Map` but this version needs just `Eq`:

```
> sortAlong "ABCDEFG" "CBGE"
"BCEG"
```